# Problema con smoothScrollToPositionFromTop android

Tags: java, android

Actualmente tengo una cuadricula nxn el cual se mueve mediante unos botones el cual oprimo puede ser de 1 al 10 (es un ejemplo) cada 1 representa una posición en la cuadricula cuando el cambia del 1 al 2 o al 3 el debera por medio de smoothScrollToPositionFromTop ir en 3 milisegundos y en animación es por ello que no utilizo otra función requiero la duración que tiene esta.

El problema con el método smoothScrollToPositionFromTop es que al ir a la posición del nuevo elemento en algunas ocaciones o queda corto o se pasa de la pantalla y al usuario le toca buscar el punto en la cuadricula si alguien me puede ayuda seria de gran ayuda.

```
gridview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position ,0,3);
```

La variable position es la que esta asignada al botón.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un problema conocido con el método `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` y aparentemente también con `smothScrollToPosition` en que el posicionamiento falla en los casos que uno tiene n elementos en la vista y trata a deslizar al elemento n+2.

Una manera simple para remediar el problema es como `setSelection(int position)`no muestra este comportamiento, llamar a `setSelection` desde un `Handler` al fin del deslizo.

```
// crear un Handler en la lista
Handler mHandler;

// en onCreate:
mHandler = new Handler();

// luego un override para smoothScrollToPositionFromTop
@Override
public void smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int position, int offset, int duration){

    final int pos = position;

    super.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset, duration);

    // Aquí se puede experimentar con duration - n para compensar el tiempo de construir y lanzar el Runnable
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){ setSelection(pos); }
    , duration );
}
```

Existen más posibilidades un poco más complejos de remediar este error, por ejemplo finalizando el deslizo en un `OnScrollListener` usando `onScroll` (después de terminar el deslizo) o `onScrollStateChanged`, que se llama siempre antes que la vista se actualiza (eso puede pasar varias veces durante un deslizo).